# Document.location.href Problem in IE

Tags: javascript

while developing a we app my requirement is to open outlook to send mail.
iam using using follwing code

document.location.href="mailTo:"+variable

Above code opens outlook in both firefox n IE but IE also redirects to document.location.href as its URL which is not possible to be opened in browser. This behavior is not found in Firefox it just opens outlook page to send mail.

Can anyone provide a fix for IE to avoid this URl redirection.

Comment: What version of IE are you talking about? I don't see this happening when I try it with IE8. Also, can you provide a more complete example of your code?

Answer (score 2):

Do to a lack of a real code that you are using, I'm guessing you are using a link (`<a>` element), and you yre not returning `false` in the onclick event handler:

```
<a href="#" onclick="sendMail(); return false;">send email</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that IE has the default e-mail client (which it presumably would invoke for a mailto URL) defined differently than Firefox does.